# .NET - extract codec information from MPEG-TS

Tags: .net, video-streaming, mpeg, subtitle

I am writing a streaming-application using VLC (VideoLAN) and its ActiveX-plugin. I am getting a stream from a satellite-decoder and now I need to get information from the stream (MPEG-TS) as to the subtitles present (for instance from a film) in the stream so I can tell the ActiveX-control which subtitle-language to use. In this case, subtitles are being sent within the stream by using Teletext.

VLC knows this information so I guess VLC must get it by reading some kind of "summary"-information from the MPEG-TS-stream. Here is an example from VLC and its debugger:

ts debug:     * ttxt type=Teletext lan=ita page=100

ts debug:     * ttxt type=Teletext subtitles lan=ita page=777

ts debug:     * ttxt type=Teletext subtitles lan=eng page=778

I need to get hold of the language and the number of the teletext-page (for instance lan=eng, page=778).

So my question is if you are aware of any library or some code which I can use within a Net-application (VB.Net or C#) to obtain some information of the MPEG-TS-stream currently playing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)